# How fast does bacta heal cuts and minor injuries?

Tags: star-wars, technology, medicine

I remember that bacta was applied to the Mandalorian by IG-74 and he seemed healed almost instantly. Also in Star Wars Resistance; Katz applied bacta to a weak alien and he seemed good to go.

My question is; how fast does bacta work on superficial cuts? Is it like Star Trek’s dermal regenerator? Near-instant healing?

I know that bacta can’t heal scars as it was unable to fully heal Vader and in the Last Jedi junior novelization it was said that Kylo waited too long to get bacta treatment which is why he had a scar on his face.

Comment: *"bacta was applied to the Mandalorian by IG-74 and he seemed healed almost instantly"* - Yup

Comment: *NOT an answer, but possibly useful* -- https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bacta

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a concrete answer, but to me it seems to depend on the severity of the injury and how quickly it can be administered. As you mention, it seems to heal Din Djarin almost immediately, and bacta grenades were used for soldiers on the battlefield. However Luke in ESB was in the bacta tank for about 12 hours, and Vader often sat in bacta in hopes to eventually heal his lungs. So my hypothesis:

Bacta can heal even near-fatal wounds almost instantaneously if administered immediately.

Severe wounds such a large burns or wounds a few hours or a day old require long sessions in a bacta tank to heal.